# Definition for "clown nose"

Tags: word-meaning

For some unfathomable reason *clown nose* seems to be absent from every monolingual dictionary (at least on the Internet), so I have to come up with my own definition for a flashcard.

Does

> A costume accessory worn by circus clowns on top of their nose,
>   typically spherical-cap-shaped and made from red foam or rubber.

sound right?

Comment: "Spherical-cap-shaped" is confusing.  Depending on your audience, you might try: "A funny nose made of a bright red ball, made famous by circus clowns"

Comment: "balled-shaped" would have probably been enough; I think I was overly pedantic with "spherical-cap-shaped".

Comment: I'll note that if you look up *[clown](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/clown_1)* in the OALD, the definition starts with "an entertainer who wears funny clothes and *a large red nose*" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 1):

You aren't finding this in a dictionary because every common adjective-noun pair can't be listed in one and only a few would be considered "compound words without hyphens."

Clown nose = a nose that a clown wears.  This is too common of a way for adjectives and nouns to work to make it noteworthy to include in a dictionary.

A phrase like ice cream, which is not simply "cream that is ice", would be an example of a two-word adjective-noun pair that should be in a dictionary.

Comment: I respectfully disagree.  There are a few different false noses that might be worn for comedic effect, like Cyrano or Orson Wells' famous collection, but a "clown nose" is always a red ball.

Comment: If you know what a clown is, and you know what a nose is, you can put two and two together to figure out what a clown nose is.  For a compound word like ice cream, that doesn't work.  I guess it's all subjective but dictionaries can't list every combination of well known concepts.